# Raspbian Jessie lite Ethernet defaults to random ip fresh install

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet, ethernet-port, jessie-lite

Fresh install of Raspbian Jessie lite, headless, on raspberry pi 2 model b

Have USB wifi dongle that connects me to network.

However Ethernet defaults to a random ip address? And then plugging in Ethernet cable doesn't do anything?

Strange that this is happening on a fresh install, tried installing reinstalling several times. Keeps defaulting to the same IP address. Also have tried multiple SD cards, multiple Ethernet cables etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If by random address you mean `169.` this is a [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) address. What you can do with this depends on what the cable is connected to.

Comment: But when I plug Ethernet cable in it doesn't pick up the network and nothing happens?